# Transaction is never mined, using web3.py

Tags: django, solidity, web3py

I'm developing a website using python 3.6, Django 2.1.1, Solidity and web3.py v4.
I want to add the transaction to ropsten testnet but the transactions are never getting confirmed. Here is the code:

```
amount_in_wei = w3.to_wei(questionEtherValue,'ether')
nonce=w3.eth.getTransactionCount(w3.toChecksumAddress(questionairAddress))+1

txn_dict = {
     'to': contractAddress,
     'value': amount_in_wei,
     'gas': 2000000,
     'gasPrice': w3.toWei('70', 'gwei'),
     'nonce': nonce,
     'chainId': 3
}
signed_txn = account.signTransaction(txn_dict)
txn_hash = w3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)

try:
    txn_receipt = w3.eth.waitForTransactionReceipt(txn_hash, timeout=300)
except Exception:
    return {'status': 'failed', 'error': 'timeout'}
else:
    return {'status': 'success', 'receipt': txn_receipt}
```

Comment: 2M gas is a lot, about a quarter of a block currently. Do you actually need all that gas? If not, you might have more luck getting transactions included with a lower gas limit.

Comment: I reduced gas limit to 30K but tx_receipt is still None!

Comment: Is `questionairAddress == w3.eth.account.privateKeyToAccount(wallet_private_key).address`?

Comment: It is a 20 byte MetaMask wallet address

Comment: I suspect you are calculating the nonce with the wrong account

Comment: I removed +1 in nonce calculation, it works!

Comment: The last edit to the question made the code invalid. `account` is no longer set up for the line `account.signTransaction`. FWIW, the code leaves more open questions, like what is `questionairAddress` and how do we know that it's the same address as the account that's signing the transaction? I think the code is much clearer if you revert the full 3rd edit: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52375369/revisions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, as @yasaman.h discovered, there is an off-by-one error in the `nonce`:

```
# original:
nonce = w3.eth.getTransactionCount(w3.toChecksumAddress(questionairAddress)) + 1

# should be:
nonce = w3.eth.getTransactionCount(w3.toChecksumAddress(questionairAddress))
```

The `nonce` of a transaction must be equal to the count of previously-sent transactions. So the first transaction sent by a new account would have a `nonce` of zero.